# plot graph that counts tweets by hour in R

Tags: r, csv, twitter, plot, hour

I am using searchtwitter function in R to extract tweets. I have also used the write.csv function to create a csv that contains a timestamp variable called "created". This is the code I used to extract time from the timestamp variable:

```
datetime<-strftime(tweets$created, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:$S")
time<-strftime(datetime, format="%H:%M:%S")
```

The csv file also contains a variable called "text" that contains the tweets. How do I extract the hour from the time variable so that I can plot the hourly frequency of tweets? This is what I've tried:

```
hour=hour(time)
plot(count(hour),xlab="Hour", ylab="No. of Tweets")
```

and:

```
plot(count(time),xlab="Hour", ylab="No. of Tweets")
```

lastly,

```
plot(time, count(text),xlab="Time", ylab="No. of Tweets")
```

Comment: This will be simplified by putting your `time` and `hour` variables into your `tweets` data.frame. You should take a look at the `table` function too, which will allow you to do `table(tweets$hour)` and `plot(table(tweets$hour)` ,  or even `barplot(tweets$hour)`

Comment: the return value of `strftime` is just a character string, so you could get the hour from `time` a number of ways.. or write your own function: `t <- function(x, what = 'hour') setNames(strsplit(x, ':')[[1]], c('hour','min','sec'))[what]; t(time)` Where are  you getting the `hour` function from? is that supposed to be `lubridate::hours`?

Comment: @rawr - `lubridate::hour` is a function, at least in my current version of R.

Comment: regardless, one would need to attach lubridate. I wonder if there is a data table solution yet